# Apigee Collection using geolocation returns entities in reverse order

Tags: apigee

when I query my collection based on a distance (i.e. 10km) the API returns the items in reverse order (i.e. farthest first). This is contrary to what the documentation states. How can I get them in the proper order. Here is my code:

```
var options = {
        type:"businesses",
        client:dataClient,
        qs:{ ql:"location within 10000 of " + geo.lat + ", " + geo.lon }
        },
        collection = new Apigee.Collection( options );

    //Call request to initiate the API call
    collection.fetch( function ( error, response ) {
        if (error) {
            //error
            console.log( error );
        } else {
            //success
            populateList( response );
        }
    });
```

Comment: Add "order by {property} asc" (or desc) to your ql string.

Comment: Order by won't help in this case, remus. The closest location would be in the middle of the list if you did order by latitude asc (near 45.000 and the list returns 44.8, 44.9, 45, 45.1, 45.2). More scratch wants the results to come back as 45, 44.9, 45.1, 44.8, 45.2... Order by location will give a 500 error as it's a collection

Comment: I ran some tests and not only does it look like the documentation is wrong, but I'm not getting all the results I should because the closest elements are at the bottom of the list and the default number of results is 10... So if I have more than 10 elements I don't see my closest results...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known bug that we are woking on.  Currently, there is no ETA of when a fix will be made.